# C# - Replacing an item in the backpack

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a simple backpack-program. It is an assignment for school and I'm almost finished except I cannot manage to replace the item in my backpack with a new one.

My guess for why it might not be working is that I cannot replace `item` because it is in the global scope but I have no idea how to fix it. Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool isRunning = true;
        while (isRunning)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\tWelcome to the backpack!");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[1]Add an item");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[2]Show contents");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[3]Clear contents");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[4]Exit");
            Console.Write("\tChoose: ");

            int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            string item;
            item = "Empty space";


            switch (menyVal)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tContents of backpack:");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t" + item);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tWhat do you want to replace " + item + " with?");
                    item = item.Replace(item, Console.ReadLine()); 
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tYou have packed " + item + " in your backpack");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tContents of backpack:");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t" + item);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tPress any key...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    item = "Tom plats";
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tYou have emptied the backpack!");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    isRunning = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Tips are much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to see what's really happening?  Step through each line, and observe the variables.

Comment: When you press 1 in the menu, the user is prompted to type in something that is supposed to replace the string stored in "item". It doesnt though, it stays the same as the first declaration "Empty space".

Comment: Since `item` is just a string, you could assign it simply `item = Console.ReadLine();` instead of using `item.Replace();`

Comment: Please read [How to debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the assignment of

```
string item;
item = "Empty space";
```

Before the while loop.

Right now, every time you loop you overwrite the item value.

Here's how the whole code would look after the change:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool isRunning = true;
        string item = "Empty space";

        while (isRunning)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\tWelcome to the backpack!");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[1]Add an item");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[2]Show contents");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[3]Clear contents");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[4]Exit");
            Console.Write("\tChoose: ");

            int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (menyVal)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tContents of backpack:");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t" + item);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tWhat do you want to replace " + item + " with?");
                    item = Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tYou have packed " + item + " in your backpack");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tContents of backpack:");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t" + item);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tPress any key...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    item = "Tom plats";
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tYou have emptied the backpack!");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    isRunning = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew that it was going to be something simple I overlooked. Totally forgot I was nested i a while-loop. *doh

Comment: `item = item.Replace(item, Console.ReadLine());` is still unnecesary; just asign `item = Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: The reason I used `item = item.Replace(item, Console.ReadLine());` is because I read on another post that it would fix my problem. it didnt so obviously I'm going back to `item = Console.ReadLine());`.

Comment: I will, you are too quick for the system so ill have to wait a bit. x)